# cypher remove null s from result

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cypher-3.1

I've created a query in neo4j :

```
MATCH (x:Node)-[r*1..2]->(y:Node) 
WITH x AS x, SIZE(COLLECT(DISTINCT y)) AS y
WITH CASE
    WHEN y=10 THEN x.target
END AS l
return l AS target
```

But returns something like :

```
target
____
null
null
"test1"
null
null
"tes56"
...
```

What I want is :

```
target
____
"test1"
"tes56"
...
```

no null in entries. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used CASE/WHEN (which does not filter out rows) when you should have been using WHERE.

Also, `size(collect(DISTINCT ))` is really just a `count(DISTINCT )` aggregation, so use that instead.

Also to avoid confusion, maybe use a different variable name for the count result.

```
MATCH (x:Node)-[*1..2]->(y:Node) 
WITH x, count(DISTINCT y) AS yCount
WHERE yCount = 10
RETURN x.target AS target
```